# is it possible to get the query plan out using jdbc on sql server?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jtds

I am using the JTDS driver and I'd like to make sure my java client is receiving the same query plan as when I execute the SQL in Mgmt studio, is there a way to get the query plan (ideally in xml format)?

basically, I'd like the same format output as

```
set showplan_xml on
```

in management studio. Any ideas?

Some code for getting the plan for a session_id

```
SELECT usecounts, cacheobjtype,
  objtype, [text], query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req, sys.dm_exec_cached_plans P
  CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
  CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)    
WHERE cacheobjtype = 'Compiled Plan'
    AND [text] NOT LIKE '%sys.dm_%'
    --and text like '%sp%reassign%'
    and p.plan_handle = req.plan_handle
    and req.session_id = 70 /** <-- your sesssion_id here **/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Identify your Java session id. Print `@@SPID` from java or use SSMS and look into [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) and/or [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) for your Java client session (it can be identified by `program_name`, `host_process_id`, `client_net_address` etc).
2. Execute your statement. Look in [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) for the `session_id` found at 1.
3. Extract the plan using [`sys.dm_exec_query_plan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747.aspx) from the `plan_handle` found at 2.
4. Save the plan as a .sqlplan file and open it in SSMS

Alternatively you can use the Profiler, attach the profiler to server and capture the [Showplan XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189318.aspx) event.

Comment: Thanks Remus, I (via Google, of course!) have knocked together some SQL for doing this taking in a session_id as a parameter, see the edit above...